# How to get parquet file schema in Node JS AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, parquet

Is there any way to read a parquet file schema from Node.JS? 
If yes, how?

I saw that there is a lib, [parquetjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs) but as I saw it from the documentation it can only read and write the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I've found that the [parquetjs-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs-lite) can do that. It does not read the whole file, just the footer and then it extracts the schema from it.

It works with a cursor and the way I saw it there is two s3.getobject calls, one for the size and one for the given data.

Comment: Do you know how to write the file to s3?